# How to add scrollbar to sidebar menu automatically if there is a long menu using javascript or jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Can anyone help me how to add scrollbar automatically if the sidebar menu is long.As i am trying to add scroll bar for sidebar menu automatically but not able to solve.Thanks in Advance.Here is my html code.

HTML:

```
<div id="menuwrapper" >
                    <ul class="MainMenu">                           
                       <li>
                            <a href="#"><strong style="margin-left:7px;">Current Openings</strong></a>                              
                        </li>
                        <li style="height: 27px;">
                            <a href="#"><strong style="margin-left:7px;">Travel Request</strong></a>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="#"><strong style="margin-left:7px;">Timesheet Management</strong></a>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="#"><strong style="margin-left:7px;">Leave Management</strong></a>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="#"><strong style="margin-left:7px;">Remuneration</strong></a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#"><strong style="margin-left:7px;">My Assets</strong></a>
                        </li>
                        </ul>
                        <div id="datepicker"></div>
                        </div>
```

Comment: Have you try to add overflow:auto to .menuwrapper ?

Comment: If i add overflow:auto to menuwrapper it will display if there is 2 menus also but i need to display if there is a long menu

Comment: @SaurabhSonawane If i add overflow:auto to menuwrapper it will display if there is 2 menus also but i need to display if there is a long menu

Comment: can you please provide your simple code on https://jsfiddle.net/ so that I can help you by looking at the snippet properly ?

Comment: @SaurabhSonawane here is the link https://jsfiddle.net/r77qnf6r/  If i add more menus scroll bar need to display if else it should not display scroll bar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried to make it but only using css

```
.MainMenu {
 width:200px;
 max-height: 200px;
 background-color:#fff;
 border:1px solid #ccc;
 overflow-x:hidden;
 overflow-y:hidden;
 transition: .5s ease;
}
.MainMenu li a {
  display: block;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  margin: 10px 0;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #777;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #f5f5f5;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

demo https://jsfiddle.net/28xwut9m/

or you can use plugin like [jQuery slimScroll](http://rocha.la/jQuery-slimScroll/)

i have update demo use jQuery-slimScroll  [check here](https://jsfiddle.net/wo05z1q2/)

Comment: I am not getting how to use jQuery slimScroll can you please change in my code That will be really helpfull for me

Comment: small change in my we have added calender as well but it is not working for calender.

Comment: but where you added slimScroll library

Comment: Can you please update in total code including library file it will be helpfull for me.If you dont mind

Comment: Update link check here it is not working :  https://jsfiddle.net/fzqzb8x5/

Comment: to more information and docs see here http://rocha.la/jQuery-slimScroll/

and this update demo : https://jsfiddle.net/wo05z1q2/

Comment: It is not working i have given my jsfiddle.net link can you please it once